# Simultaneous routed WIFI and ad hoc WIFI

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, windows-11

I would like to have two separate networks within my home.  One would be strictly limited to my home PCs (i.e. no internet access).  This would allow me to Remote Desktop between my desktop and my server.  The other would be a standard WIFI network.  With my current single network, my server uses NordVPN, and any time it drops a connection (which happens frequently), Remote Desktop stops working.  Since my server is headless, I have to do a hard reboot to restore Remote Desktop.

So, I've installed two WIFI adapters in both my desktop machine and my server.  I tried the steps shown on multiple web sites:

`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=mynetwork_adhoc key=redacted`

to setup an ad hoc network (which I believe is how to create the no internet access network), but it doesn't identify which network adapter to use for this new network, and it ended up just assigning both adapters to the same network (and it was the existing internet enabled network, NOT the ssid stated in the netsh wlan statement.

First, is my assumption correct that an ad hoc network wouldn't have access to the internet?

Second, how do I tell the netsh wlan command which adapter to use when creating the new network?

My desktop is Windows 10 Pro and my server is Windows 11 Pro.